# Rails4.2 gemのactiveadminについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

gemのactiveadminを使っているのですが、activeadminから新規作成をする場合にレコード一個目は作成できるのですが、それ以降新規作成ができません

新規作成を押すと`http://localhost:3000/admin/presses/new`に飛ぶのですがそれはすでに作成したレコードの編集画面なのです。

原因はApplicationControllerで下記のコードをbefore_actionしているせいでした。

```
  def press
    @press = Press.last
  end
```

上記をしないと新着ニュースがすべての画面で表示できなくなります。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@press`ではなく`@recent_press`などに変数名を変えればいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
今までダメだった原因がわかりました！